# Javascript make an object from array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this: `var arr = ["1:a", "2:b", "3:c"];`

From above array I want an object:  `var obj = { "1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c" }`

I am doing:

```
  var obj = {}
    $.each(arr, function (i, value) {
        var valueSplit = value.split(':');
// I don't know how to make the object
    });
```

Edit: 
My Question is mark as duplicate, while the question I asked is totally opposite of the marked duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the assignment.

```
var obj = {}
$.each(arr, function (i, value) {
    var valueSplit = value.split(':');
    obj[valueSplit[0]] = valueSplit[1]; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code, in place of the comment you could write

```
obj[valueSplit[0]] = valueSplit[1];
```

This could be written as a simple reduce:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(x,y) { return z = y.split(':'), x[z[0]]=z[1], x; }, {});
```

```js
var arr = ["1:a", "2:b", "3:c"];
var obj = arr.reduce(function(x,y) { return z = y.split(':'), x[z[0]]=z[1], x; }, {});
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: This would be my preferred approach over using jQuery's `$.each`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
var arr = ["1:a", "2:b", "3:c"];
var map = {};
arr.forEach( function(val){ 
   var keyVal = val.split( ":" ); 
   map[ keyVal[ 0 ] ] = keyVal[ 1 ];
});
```

`map` is the object you are looking for.

**DEMO**

```js
var arr = ["1:a", "2:b", "3:c"];
var map = {};
arr.forEach( function(val){ 
   var keyVal = val.split( ":" ); 
   map[ keyVal[ 0 ] ] = keyVal[ 1 ];
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( map, 0, 4 );
```